# Time series forecasting using Fable in R; determining most optimum combination of models for mixed model

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, fable-r

I am doing some time series forecasting analysis with the `fable` and `fabletools` package and I am interested in comparing the accuracy of individual models and also a mixed model (consisting of the individual models I am using).

Here is some example code with a mock dataframe:-

```
library(fable)
library(fabletools)
library(distributional)
library(tidyverse)
library(imputeTS)

#creating mock dataframe
set.seed(1)  

Date<-seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2021-03-19"), by = "1 day")

Count<-rnorm(length(Date),mean = 2086, sd= 728)

Count<-round(Count)

df<-data.frame(Date,Count)

df

#===================redoing with new model================

df$Count<-abs(df$Count)#in case there is any negative values, force them to be absolute

count_data<-as_tsibble(df)

count_data<-imputeTS::na.mean(count_data)

testfrac<-count_data%>%arrange(Date)%>%sample_frac(0.8)
lastdate<-last(testfrac$Date)

#train data
train <- count_data %>%
  #sample_frac(0.8)
  filter(Date<=as.Date(lastdate))
set.seed(1)
fit <- train %>%
  model(
    ets = ETS(Count),
    arima = ARIMA(Count),
    snaive = SNAIVE(Count),
    croston= CROSTON(Count),
    ave=MEAN(Count),
    naive=NAIVE(Count),
    neural=NNETAR(Count),
    lm=TSLM(Count ~ trend()+season())
  ) %>%
  mutate(mixed = (ets + arima + snaive + croston + ave + naive + neural + lm) /8)# creates a combined model using the averages of all individual models 


fc <- fit %>% forecast(h = 7)

accuracy(fc,count_data)

fc_accuracy <- accuracy(fc, count_data,
                        measures = list(
                          point_accuracy_measures,
                          interval_accuracy_measures,
                          distribution_accuracy_measures
                        )
)

fc_accuracy

# A tibble: 9 x 13
#  .model  .type     ME  RMSE   MAE   MPE  MAPE  MASE RMSSE   ACF1 winkler percentile  CRPS
#  <chr>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1 arima   Test  -191.   983.  744. -38.1  51.8 0.939 0.967 -0.308   5769.       567.  561.
#2 ave     Test  -191.   983.  744. -38.1  51.8 0.939 0.967 -0.308   5765.       566.  561.
#3 croston Test  -191.   983.  745. -38.2  51.9 0.940 0.968 -0.308  29788.       745.  745.
#4 ets     Test  -189.   983.  743. -38.0  51.7 0.938 0.967 -0.308   5759.       566.  560.
#5 lm      Test  -154.  1017.  742. -36.5  51.1 0.937 1.00  -0.307   6417.       583.  577.
#6 mixed   Test  -173.   997.  747. -36.8  51.1 0.944 0.981 -0.328  29897.       747.  747.
#7 naive   Test    99.9  970.  612. -19.0  38.7 0.772 0.954 -0.308   7856.       692.  685.
#8 neural  Test  -322.  1139.  934. -49.6  66.3 1.18  1.12  -0.404  26361.       852.  848.
#9 snaive  Test  -244   1192.  896. -37.1  55.5 1.13  1.17  -0.244   4663.       690.  683.
```

I demonstrate how to create a mixed model. However, there can be some individual models which hamper the performance of a mixed model when added to it; in other words, the mixed model could be potentially improved if it did not include the individual models which skews the accuracy in a detrimental way.

**Desired outcome**

What I would like to achieve is to be able to test all of the possible combinations of individual models and returns the mixed model with the most optimum performance on one of the accuracy metrics, for instance, Mean Absolute Error (MAE). But I am not sure how to do this in an automated way as there are many potential combinations.

Can someone suggest or share some code as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to consider:

- While it's definitely desirable to quickly evaluate the performance of many combination models, it's pretty impractical. The best option would be to evaluate your models individually, and then create a more simple combination using, e.g. the 2 or 3 best ones
- As an example, consider that you can actually have *weighted* combinations - e.g. `0.75 * ets + 0.25 * arima`. The possibilities are now literally endless, so you start to see the limitations of the brute-force method (N.B. I don't think `fable` actually supports these kind of combinations yet though).

That, said, here's one approach you could use to generate all the possible combinations. Note that this might take a prohibitively long time to run - but should give you what you're after.

```
# Get a table of models to get combinations from
fit <- train %>%
  model(
    ets = ETS(Count),
    arima = ARIMA(Count),
    snaive = SNAIVE(Count),
    croston= CROSTON(Count),
    ave=MEAN(Count),
    naive=NAIVE(Count),
    neural=NNETAR(Count),
    lm=TSLM(Count ~ trend()+season())
  )

# Start with a vector containing all the models we want to combine
models <- c("ets", "arima", "snaive", "croston", "ave", "naive", "neural", "lm")

# Generate a table of combinations - if a value is 1, that indicates that
# the model should be included in the combinations
combinations <- models %>% 
  purrr::set_names() %>% 
  map(~0:1) %>% 
  tidyr::crossing(!!!.)

combinations
#> # A tibble: 256 x 8
#>      ets arima snaive croston   ave naive neural    lm
#>    <int> <int>  <int>   <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int>
#>  1     0     0      0       0     0     0      0     0
#>  2     0     0      0       0     0     0      0     1
#>  3     0     0      0       0     0     0      1     0
#>  4     0     0      0       0     0     0      1     1
#>  5     0     0      0       0     0     1      0     0
#>  6     0     0      0       0     0     1      0     1
#>  7     0     0      0       0     0     1      1     0
#>  8     0     0      0       0     0     1      1     1
#>  9     0     0      0       0     1     0      0     0
#> 10     0     0      0       0     1     0      0     1
#> # ... with 246 more rows

# This just filters for combinations with at least 2 models
relevant_combinations <- combinations %>% 
  filter(rowSums(across()) > 1)

# We can use this table to generate the code we would put in a call to `mutate()`
# to generate the combination. {fable} does something funny with code
# evaluation here, meaning that more elegant approaches are more trouble 
# than they're worth
specs <- relevant_combinations %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "model", values_to = "flag_present") %>% 
  filter(flag_present == 1) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(
    desc = glue::glue_collapse(model, "_"),
    model = glue::glue(
      "({model_sums}) / {n_models}",
      model_sums = glue::glue_collapse(model, " + "),
      n_models = n()
    )
  ) %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = desc, values_from = model)

# This is what the `specs` table looks like:
specs
#> # A tibble: 1 x 247
#>   neural_lm         naive_lm  naive_neural  naive_neural_lm   ave_lm  ave_neural
#>   <glue>            <glue>    <glue>        <glue>            <glue>  <glue>    
#> 1 (neural + lm) / 2 (naive +~ (naive + neu~ (naive + neural ~ (ave +~ (ave + ne~
#> # ... with 241 more variables: ave_neural_lm <glue>, ave_naive <glue>,
#> #   ave_naive_lm <glue>, ave_naive_neural <glue>, ave_naive_neural_lm <glue>,
#> #   croston_lm <glue>, croston_neural <glue>, croston_neural_lm <glue>,
#> #   croston_naive <glue>, croston_naive_lm <glue>, croston_naive_neural <glue>,
#> #   croston_naive_neural_lm <glue>, croston_ave <glue>, croston_ave_lm <glue>,
#> #   croston_ave_neural <glue>, croston_ave_neural_lm <glue>,
#> #   croston_ave_naive <glue>, croston_ave_naive_lm <glue>, ...

# We can combine our two tables and evaluate the generated code to produce 
# combination models as follows:
combinations <- fit %>% 
  bind_cols(rename_with(specs, ~paste0("spec_", .))) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("spec"), ~eval(parse(text = .))))

# Compute the accuracy for 2 random combinations to demonstrate:
combinations %>% 
  select(sample(seq_len(ncol(.)), 2)) %>% 
  forecast(h = 7) %>% 
  accuracy(count_data, measures = list(
    point_accuracy_measures,
    interval_accuracy_measures,
    distribution_accuracy_measures
  ))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 13
#>   .model          .type    ME  RMSE   MAE   MPE  MAPE  MASE RMSSE   ACF1 winkler
#>   <chr>           <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 spec_ets_arima~ Test  -209. 1014.  771. -40.1  54.0 0.973 0.998 -0.327  30825.
#> 2 spec_ets_snaiv~ Test  -145.  983.  726. -34.5  48.9 0.917 0.967 -0.316  29052.
#> # ... with 2 more variables: percentile <dbl>, CRPS <dbl>
```

Comment: Brilliant, very detailed answer and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!